# Looping ggplot across many variables

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, iteration

############
EDIT
############

I used this info_mat to compute evolution rates.

```
date1 <- rbind("February", "March",   "April",     "May",       "June",      "July",      "August",    "September", "October",   "November")
sum1.visit_bush. <- rbind("0", "0" ,"1"  , "-0.75" ,"2","0" ,"0.333333333333333" , "1.25"  , "0",  "-1")
sum1.counts_bush. <- rbind("0" ,"0.115290451813933", "-0.557273997206146", "0.146270002253775" ,  "0.100865119937082", "0.512412930880514",  "0.435049598488427",   "-0.0831961816984858", "0.824791311372408",  "-0.156025577963601" )
sum1.hcounts_bush. <- rbind("0",  "0.0387010676156584", "-0.625695931477516", "0.47254004576659",  "-0.233100233100233", "0.99290780141844" ,  "-0.032536858159634" , "0.349973725696269" , "0.660957571039315",  "-0.341223341926412")
evolution1 <- data.frame(date1, sum1.visit_bush., sum1.counts_bush., sum1.hcounts_bush.)
```

I then proceed as you suggested

```
df_month_cand <- evolution1 %>% select(c("date", paste0(c("sum.visit_", "sum.counts_", "sum.hcounts_"), "bush.")))
df_month_cand_plot <- melt(df_month_cand, id.vars = "date", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "y")

FunctionPlot <- function(cand, evolution) {
  df_month_cand <- evolution %>% select(c("date1", paste0(c("sum1.visit_", "sum1.counts_", "sum1.hcounts_"), cand)))
  df_month_cand_plot <- melt(df_month_cand, id.vars = "date1", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "y")
  
  p <- ggplot(df_month_cand_plot, aes(x = date1, y = y, color = Type)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group=Type)) +
    labs(
      title = paste0("Evolution of visits and coverage
      per month for ", cand) ,
      subtitle = "We read: from March to April, whereas the visits of -candidate- increased by -value*100 %-, 
    the coverage in newspapers decreased by -value*100 %-",
      color="Type", 
      x="Months", 
      y="Percentage change over months") + 
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold", margin = margin(5, 0, 10, 10), vjust=2, hjust=0.5),
      axis.text.x=element_text(angle=50, size=11.5, vjust=0.5),
      axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=4),
      plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6), "cm"),
      legend.position = "bottom", 
      legend.box.background = element_rect(color="black", size=2), 
      legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size=10), 
      legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90",
                                       size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                       colour ="black"), 
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray90", colour = "gray70", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'dashed', colour = "gray75")) +
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("Visits", "Main text count", "Headline count"), values = c("tomato3", "deepskyblue3", "green2")) + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November")) + 
    scale_y_discrete()
  plot(p)
}

sapply("bush.", FunctionPlot, evolution1)
```

However, on the output the y axis is completely messed-up.
The values are not sorted from least to greatest.
Why? How to resolve this?

Lastly, to simplify the y axis I'd like to divide is from -1 to 2 with breaks of 0.25
I tried

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1, 2, 0.25))
```

But I have the following error code:
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Where does `info_mat` come from? Is there a way to make your question reproducible?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert you variable `date` from character to Date format:

```
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%d-%m")
```

`ggplot` can print dates at X axes. Now you don't need to create variable months by hand.
I think you should work with data.frame:

```
df_info <- data.frame(
    date = date,
    a1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    hb1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    a2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    b2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    hb2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    a3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    b3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    hb3 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    a4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    b4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    hb4 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1)
)
```

Or if you have big data you can convert matrix to data.frame  with converting variables to numeric format (but without names).

```
df_info <- bind_cols(data.frame(date = date), info_mat[,-1] %>% as.data.frame() %>% lapply(as.numeric)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Now we can select columns for first individual:

```
df <- df_info %>% select(c("date", paste0(c("a", "b", "hb"), 1)))
```

Next we will create data.frame for plot:

```
    df_plot <- melt(df, id.vars = "date", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "y")
```

Your function for plot is good you can use it for `df_plot`. Now let's create function for plotting data for fixed number of individual:

```
f <- function(num, df_info) {
    df <- df_info %>% select(c("date", paste0(c("a", "b", "hb"), num)))
    
    df_plot <- melt(df, id.vars = "date", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "y")
    
    p <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = date, y = y, color = `Type`)) + geom_point() +
        geom_line() +
        labs(
            title = "Evolution of a and b and c per months",
            subtitle = paste0("plot ", num),
            color="Type", 
            x = "Months", 
            y = "over months"
        )
    plot(p)
}
```

Let's apply our function for each number of individual:

```
sapply(1:4, f, df_info)
```

Or

```
sapply(1:4, function(x) f(x, df_info))
```

But your data has bad scale. You cannot see the difference between 0 and 1 if you have 6421 on the same plot. but I don't know what you want to do with this data and plots.
[image]

Comment: Almost there!! Instead of my individuals being 1:4 they have names. Respectively "bush.", "obama.", "trump.", "lieberman." Based on what you said, I tried the following: sapply("bush.":"lieberman.", f info) and this doesn't work. Everything else before works!

Comment: To be explicit. In the dataframe, my variables are not a1, b1, ... but a_bush. ; b_bush. ; hb_bush. etc.

Comment: The problem does not come from anything except this syntax "bush.":"lieberman." The function works perfectly if I input one candidate: sapply("bush.", f, info) works

Comment: I think you need to change in `f` part from `paste0(c("a", "b", "hb"), num))` to `paste0(c("a", "b", "hb"), "_",  num))` where `num` is a name of person (you can rename it in `f` input). So you can run `sapply(c("bush", "lieberman"), f, df_info)` (or "bush." with dot at the end).

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question I'm sorry Please see the edit

Comment: Please see the edit now, I cleaned the code

Comment: You variables are character, cause they sorted by name and negative numbers have bad orders. Use `evolution1[, -1] <- evolution1[, -1] %>% lapply(as.numeric)` after `evolution1` creating (I don't want to change date format because I use `[,-1]`). Or make your vectors numeric by hand: `sum1.visit_bush. <- as.numeric(c("0", "0" ,"1"  , "-0.75" ,"2","0" ,"0.333333333333333" , "1.25"  , "0",  "-1"))`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your very precious help