# R looping matrix elements

Tags: r, loops, matrix, tidyverse

I'm trying to loop over matrix columns.

```
date <- rbind("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-08", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-12")
a1 <- rbind("0", "0", "0", "0", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
b1 <- rbind("1", "1", "1", "1", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
hb1 <- rbind("2", "2", "2", "2", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
a2 <- rbind("0", "0", "0", "0", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
b2 <- rbind("1", "1", "1", "1", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
hb2 <- rbind("2", "2", "2", "2", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
a3 <- rbind("0", "0", "0", "0", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
b3 <- rbind("1", "1", "1", "1", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
hb3 <- rbind("2", "2", "2", "2", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
a4 <- rbind("0", "0", "0", "0", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
b4 <- rbind("1", "1", "1", "1", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
hb4 <- rbind("2", "2", "2", "2", "6421", "41", "5667", "44", "1178", "0", "1070", "1")
info_mat <- cbind(date, a1, b1, hb1, a2, b2, hb2, a3, b3, hb3, a4, b4, hb4)
print(info_mat)
```

I want to compute an evolution rate (V+1 - V)/V between the months for each variable
(evolution from January to Feb, Feb to March, ..., for a1, ..., hb4)
and get the result in a matrix that I will name "evolution_matrix"

I tried the following but for some reason it won't work.
Note that i represents here the fact that I want to perform the evolution for every variable. I think of i as being:
Evolution(January to February for variable a1) =
(value of a1 in February - value of a1 in January)/(value of a1 in January).

I don't know how to model it therefore I put i, but it doesn't refer to anything in the matrix.

```
  for(row in 1:nrow(info_mat)) {
    for(col in 1:ncol(info_mat)) {
      evolution[[i]] = (info_mat[i+1] - info_mat[i] )/info_mat[i]
    print(evolution[[i]])
    }
  }
```

Help please!

Comment: What is `i` inside the loop?

Comment: The example data is a character matrix, we can't do math on it, update your example. There is an `i` inside forloops where is it coming from?

Comment: Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use matrix? You have only character (string) variables in matrix, but you want to use them as numbers. I think data.frame is good idea.
R package `dplyr` has function lapply which can apply your function to each column and simplify the result by list. But we don't want to apply 'evolution' function for column date.

```
evolution <- as.data.frame(info_mat)[, -1] %>% 
    lapply(function(x) {x = as.numeric(x); (x - lag(x)) / lag(x)}) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

In the last line I convert list to data.frame (for beautiful printing).
But we forgot about 'date' column. Let's add it into our data.frame.

```
evolution <- bind_cols(data.frame(date = date), evolution)
```

That is all. But if you want to do it by loop you can use this code:

```
evolution <- matrix(NA, nrow(info_mat), ncol(info_mat))
evolution[, 1] <- date
for(row in 2:nrow(info_mat)) {
    for(col in 2:ncol(info_mat)) {
        evolution[row, col] = as.numeric(info_mat[row, col])/as.numeric(info_mat[row - 1, col]) - 1
    }
}
```

Comments about your example of code:

1. you have no variable `i` and don't use variables `row` and `col`.
2. what is the type of `evolution` variable?
3. `info_mat[i+1]` is not numeric. You cannot divide it on `info_mat[i]`.
4. What does `info_mat[i]` means? Yes, `info_mat[row, col]` is equal to `info_mat[(col - 1)* 12 (number of rows) + row]` but `info_mat[i]` and `info_mat[i + 1]` can be in different columns.

And if you want to create data.frame with you data use this code:

```
df = data.frame(
    data = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-08", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-12"),
    a1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1),
    b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6421, 41, 5667, 44, 1178, 0, 1070, 1)
)
```

Comment: By change, @erop, can you take a look at this? Maybe you would be able to use a similar reasoning. Thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058488/looping-ggplot-across-many-variables?noredirect=1#comment123846717_70058488